# Не срабатывает MySQL-функция database() в триггере

Tags: mysql, триггер

Решил воспользоваться в триггере конструкцией

```
SET next_id = 
   (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
       FROM information_schema.TABLES 
      WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME='tname');
```

не сработало. В phpMyAdmin удалось выяснить следующее:

1. `select database()` возвращает имя базы
2. `select * from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA=имя_базы` срабатывает правильно
3. `select * from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA=database()` возвращает поля с `TABLE_SCHEMA` равным `information_schema`

MySql 5.5, если что

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ну собственно не убедились, что с условием `TABLE_NAME='tname'` выбирает ровно одну запись. И очень интересно, зачем в триггере может понадобится такая конструкция. Ибо получение id не через get_last_id() приведет к потенциальным проблемам.

Comment: 1) убедился. 2) нужно, чтобы инициализировать еще одно поле, если оно не заполнено, этим значением. в триггере после нельзя обновлять, в триггере до еще не заполнено

Comment: справиться - я справился, усложнив запросы, но судя по гуглу, должно работать

Answer (score 1):

Триггер рабочий, скорее всего проблема в контексте вызова. Возможно где-то вызывается запрос с полным квалифицированным именем таблицы, с указанием базы данных. В этом случае выбора базы данных не осуществляется и функция `DATABASE()` возвращает `NULL`. Вообще функции `DATABASE()` и `USER()` очень коварны, так как в разных условиях могут выдавать разные значения, ломая логику базы данных, если она на них завязывается (особенно жестко это дает о себе знать во время репликации).

В запросе

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
```

Вы явно указываете имя базы данных `information_schema`, которая становится текущей и возвращается функцией `DATABASE()`. В кругу SQL-программистов у этой функции дурная слава, особенно, если вам потом придется масштабироваться репликацией на несколько серверов.

Comment: в том и проблема, я планирую таскать базу, это означает, что надо будет лазить в триггер и поправлять :( Самое удивительное для меня, что и в phpMyAdmin результат такой странный

Comment: в общем, я усложнил запросы и выбросил это место из триггера, но ясности не добавило :)

Comment: Смотрите, вот в этом запросе select * from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA=database() вы явно запросили inforfation_schema в from. Может тут собака порылась?

Comment: он рисует 40 столбцов, в которых колонка TABLE_SCHEMA должна быть равна базе, а не 'information_schema'. А получаются именно они

Comment: Да, потому что information_schema - это тоже база данных и вы её выбрали при помощи information_schema.tables - теперь она текущая

Comment: о!!! вот оно как!!