# MySql: дублирование AUTO_INCREMENT значения при INSERT-вставке

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица:

1. id - auto_increment
2. body
3. thread

Есть запрос к БД

```
INSERT INTO `post` SET `body` = '123',  `thread` = 'id'
```

Нужно что бы например в поле thread было такое же значение как auto_increment у id
Возможно ли без второго запроса и без php?

Comment: Боюсь только триггер делать, который в случае если thread не задан будет приравнивать его к ID (NEW.thread=NEW.id)

Comment: @Mike, так у меня не получилось :( после инсерт нельзя, а до - он  неизвестен

Comment: я даже через "одно место" пробовал сделать - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/502875/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-mysql-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-database-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5 -  все равно не вышло :) В результате в селекте на null в поле возвращаю id

Comment: @splash58 А в MySQL можно в триггере AFTER FOR EACH ROW давать update на ту же таблицу, на которую триггер ? Ну типа позволить колонке быть NULL и в триггере дать `update tabX set thread=id where id=NEW.id and thread is null`

Comment: боюсь соврать, но по-моему туже таблицу нельзя трогать. Я точно такой вариант должен был попробовать

Comment: это удивительно, но на эту тему сотни ссылок, в том числе на SO, но решения я не нашел

Comment: @splash58 Интересно устроит ли автора вопроса триггер в принципе. Думаю можно придумать триггерное решение, правда если update дать нельзя придется городить временную таблицу и использовать триггер `for statement` по крайней мере в oracle если надо из триггера обратится к той же таблице приходится во временной фиксировать все ID, а потом на statement триггере работать с ними так как update таблицы уже доступен

Comment: это ужасно :) я выбрался, добавив условие, на ноль во селекте и при поиске в where. Решив, что это проще. Но, конечно, зависит от задачи

Comment: @Mike кстати, есть еще решение сделать маленькую таблицу просто с автоинкремент id, и брать оттуда. я когда то так две таблицы синхронно вел

Comment: @Mike то что нельзя делать новые запросы это я написал думал есть не костыльные варианты. Все таки сделаю через php заполнение null на их id

Comment: @WaQum тогда проще сразу после insert (при котором thread сделать скажем NULL или 0) сделать `update tabX set thread=last_insert_id() where id=last_insert_id()`

Comment: @Mike если это php - библиотека возврашает вставленный id. Так что, совсем просто

Comment: @Mike спасибо, так и сделаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Механизм AUTO_INCREMENT имеет ограничение, им можно снабдить только один столбец таблицы и он у вас назначен столбцу `id`. Для дублирования значения проще всего воспользоваться триггером:

```
CREATE TRIGGER id_to_thread
BEFORE INSERT ON post
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET @id := (SELECT
                AUTO_INCREMENT
              FROM
                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
              WHERE
                TABLE_NAME = 'post' AND
                TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
              );
  SET NEW.thread = @id;
END//
```

В триггере через информационную схему выясняется, какое значение будет назначено идентификатору `id` по механизму AUTO_INCREMENT. Полученное значение назначается полю `thread` перед вставкой записи в таблицу `post`.

Для того, чтобы анализатор мог отделить конец запроса от точек с запятой в теле триггера, нужно изменить признак конца запроса (например, на //). В mysql-консоли для этого предназначена специальная команда `DELIMITER`

```
DELIMITER //
```

Большинство других mysql-клиентов также имеют возможность пометь признак конца запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте mysql LAST_INSERT_ID. Что-то типа такого:

```
INSERT INTO `post` (`id`, `body`) VALUES (NULL, '123');
SET @lastID := LAST_INSERT_ID();
UPDATE `post` SET `thread`=@lastID WHERE `id`=@lastID;
```

Comment: А каким образом сработает `on duplicate key` при создании заведомо новой записи ? (на случай если я что то не понимаю, я проверил ваш запрос, он вставил NULL в thread)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id LAST_INSERT_ID().

Comment: И ? Что там такого написано ? last_insert_id() возвращает ID последнего успешно выполненного запроса, но к сожалению уже после выполнения insert. т.е. необходим второй запрос что бы использовать эту функцию. А on duplicate тут вообще не причем, он сработает только если запись, которую пытаются вставить уже существует

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID сохраняй в переменную и делай +1

Comment: @DmitryKalinin этого никто не обещает, что следующий будет +1

Comment: INSERT INTO `post` (`id`, `body`) VALUES (NULL, '123');
SET @lastID := LAST_INSERT_ID();
UPDATE `post` SET `thread`=@lastID WHERE `id`=@lastID;

Вот простой пример.

Comment: *Возможно ли без второго запроса*

Comment: @splash58 обещает auto_increment

Comment: я могу перезапустить автоинкремент, и он пойдет по дыркам.

Comment: @splash58 чувак ты меня минусанул ну то ладно, ты читал код? LAST_INSERT_ID() он берет послдений, причем тут дырки? перезапускай все будет работать нормально.

INSERT INTO `post` (`id`, `body`) VALUES (NULL, '123');
SET @lastID := LAST_INSERT_ID();
UPDATE `post` SET `thread`=@lastID WHERE `id`=@lastID;

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39545/discussion-between-dmitry-kalinin-and-splash58).

Comment: во первых, мне не нравится чувак. во вторых я не минусовал.

Comment: @splash58 если для тебя on duplicate key сложный используй простой пример который я описал. Обрати внимание что делает LAST_INSERT_ID это функция из mysql.